# Is there a BASH script allowing me to grep from /var/log/messages?

Tags: bash, logging, scripting, code-organization

I am in need of a script (if one exists, not confident in my own scripting ability) that is able to bring up specified information from the /var/log/messages. I need to show logged traffic on specific dates and times and protocols (ie. Show all insecure FTP traffic on October 23 between 12:30pm and 12:35pm). Is there a script that can do this, or is anyone able to perhaps create a quick simple one that can do the job?

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, StackOverflow's scope is limited to "practical, answerable problems *unique to software development*". Searching logs is not a problem unique to software development. Moreover, off-site resource requests (ie. "can you help me find a tool/site/etc that does X?") are item #4 in the list headed "Some items are still off-topic".

Comment: ...oh, heh, there's actually a directly applicable comment at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments/136610. Quoting: **Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.**

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I have, although it is not working completely:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter month (first 3 letters): " month

read -p "Enter day of month: " day

read -p "Enter starting time (HH:MM:SS): " stime

read -p "Enter ending time (HH:MM:SS): " ftime

read -p "Enter chain: " chain

read -p "Enter any other modifiers (TTL, SRC, DSP, SPT, DPT, IN, OUT, etc): " modifier

if [ -z "$month" ]; then
    month='IN='
fi

if [ -z "$chain" ]; then
    chain='IN='
fi

if [ -z "$modifier" ]; then
    modifier='IN='
fi

if [ -z "$stime" ] && [ -z "$ftime" ]; then

cat /var/log/messages | grep -i "$month $day" | grep -i $chain | grep -i $modifier

else

cat /var/log/messages | grep -i "$month $day" | grep -i $chain | grep -i $modifier | sed -n "/$stime/,/$ftime/p"

fi
```

It isnt working well but its better than nothing. Perhaps it can be improved